# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

code :

```
import java.sql.*;    
class Test    
{

public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException ,SQLException    
{

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");    
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xyz","system","xyz");
System.out.println("connection established");    
}       
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No data found
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7138)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3073)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Test.main(jdbctest.java:9)
```

Comment: It is highly likely you have not configured the JDBC/ODBC diver correctly.  I presume the database is MSAccess and not Oracle.  Ensure your ODBC data source points to the correct Access file

Answer (score 0):

I think your driver name is not well set. If you want to connect to an Oracle database then you can use *oracle jdbc* drivers. You use the demo code below:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class OracleJDBC {

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mkyong", "username",
                "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}

}
```

For more information consult the full tutorial [Connect to Oracle DB via JDBC driver](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/).

Comment: cdaiga.... I am trying to use odbc ie type1 driver, I am not using type4 thin driver

Comment: @xyz Why would you want to use Type 1? The `JdbcOdbcDriver` has been removed from Java 8 as it isn't a very good driver. Using vendor specific (type 2 or type 4) drivers is usually a better choice.